# database choice to record museum object

Tags: database

I am working in a museum and I would like to create a database that record each object belonging to the collection. I have already created a database with Filemaker pro but I find this software far too expensive and I am would like to use an open source software. 
There are so many possibilities and I don't really know which software would suit the best to my project. I am therefore seeking for advices.

I am searching an open source database that meets the 2 following criteria: 
1°) Easy display of image in the final layout of the database
2°) Possibility to organizes the final layout. I don't really find the use of a table easy to read. For example, with Filemaker Pro, I can organize each field (artist, date, title, etc...) allowing me to display them as I want.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a number of open-source, web-based projects on GitHub, including Providence by [CollectiveAccess](https://github.com/collectiveaccess) and [Ennigaldi](https://github.com/arq-abaco/ennigaldi). The former is feature-rich but less flexible, while the latter is still in early development, but can be more easily customized since it is built on top of Django.

That said, this sort of question --- "best practices" and so on --- is generally frowned upon in StackOverflow and will probably be locked down.

Comment: Dear Pedro, thank you for your answer and advices, I will have a look at the 2 possibilities you mentionned !